# How to get a specific array value on a passed array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web, frameworks

I have this controller where all the available users and its respective information are passed in the view through an array:

```
function view() {

    $data = array();

    if($query = $this->m_user->get_user()) {
        $data['user'] = $query;
    }

    $this->load->view('v_view_user', $data);

    }
```

In my view I used this method (the norm) to view all that was passed:

```
<?php echo "user_name here" ?>
<?php if(isset($user)) : foreach ($user as $row) : 
echo $row->user_name;

   end foreach;
end if;
?>
```

What I want to do is to print a specific index (the name to be specific) before the code given above.

For the model:

```
function get_employees() {
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

By the way, the array contains user_id, user_name, user_family_name, ..., [and other more].

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: **specific index** means you want to display only user_name?

Comment: @kumar_v indeed, yes.

Comment: can you add te content of $query in question?

Comment: @kumar_v updated the question. The array contains user_id, user_name, user_family_name, ..., [and other more]. I need to print the user_name outside the loop.

Comment: @kumar_v your answer does help, but I updated the question. Hope you can give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query->result();` will return the array of objects. So you can get user_name as below:

```
<?php if(isset($user)) : foreach ($user as $row) :

   echo $row->user_name;

   end foreach;
end if;
?>
```

**EDIT:** After question updated with my answer

you can use below code to get outside the loop:

```
echo $user[0]->user_name; // returns the first user_name
```

Comment: yes  you can do like `echo $user[0]->user_name;` This will print first user name. If you want all, the you have to use loop.